# Access button to insert code directly from a form to linked table in SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Sorry if this has been asked before but I have looked and although I can find similar results they haven't helped me.
I have a little project to go through and check names and address. I have two tables with names and addresses which are full of mistakes and duplicates. I have matched these with SQL but my boss wants a clerical check of a few hundred to show how accurate the SQL matching was.
To do this I have created a form with subforms below which are linked to the SQLServer database. The basic premise is the main form shows the matched result and the subform shows the corresponding match in the other tables.
I have made a button to click when you are happy with the match. It is intended to place a "yes" beside the result in the matched result form. Using the work id from the main form as the match key

The code for the button is

```
STRSQL = "UPDATE dbo_reference_table SET Match = 'YES' WHERE work_ID = '"& me.work_id & "'"
DoCmd.Runsql (STRSQL)
```

However when I run the code I keep getting:

> Runtime error '3362' Single row update/delete affected more than one
> row in a linked table. Unique index contains duplicate values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are Match and work_ID both text type fields? Is this intended to UPDATE multiple records?

Comment: Hi Work_id is an INT and Match is Varchr.

Comment: No its not intended to update multiple fields as each work_ID is unique.

Comment: Don't use apostrophe delimiters for number type field. But if form displays intended record and that record has focus, could just set value of control: `Me.Match = "Yes"`. Or maybe simply do manual edit directly to the intended record. Exactly where is the button positioned?